# Conversion fails when exporting excel spreadsheet through Google Documents List API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

We are using the Google Docs List API to export different document types and we encountered the following error for a specific spreadsheet when trying to ask for it in xls format:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Conversion failed unexpectedly
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Conversion failed unexpectedly</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Conversion failed unexpectedly</H1>
<H2>Error 500</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:624)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource(MediaService.java:234)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:276)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:302)
```

This error has persisted for several days for that same spreadsheet. We have investigated a bit on our own and concluded that the formats that fail to export are xls/xlsx and ods, but that for example csv and html works. This is how our REST calls look:

```
fails: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={ID}&xoauth_requestor_id={email}&exportFormat=xls
fails: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={ID}&xoauth_requestor_id={email}&exportFormat=ods
succeeds: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={ID}&xoauth_requestor_id={email}&exportFormat=csv
```

We also tried adding the old `format=` attribute but it did not change the behaviour so we removed it again.

Since the Google Docs is being replaced by Google Drive we are going to look at converting to the Google Drive API next year, which might work, but in the meantime it would be nice to be able to solve this in the current version.

On our side, I am trying to get in contact with the customer to see if they can see anything odd in the actual spreadsheet. I will add any information I find as I get it.

Searches on Google do not come up with much, so I hope that someone here has seen this before and knows some scenarios where this can happen. Any comments from anyone who saw this before and what you did to get around it will be helpful!

Thanks in advance!